# How to get the current server timestamp using spring boot actuator

Tags: java, spring-boot-actuator

I'm using spring boot actuator to monitor the health of my micro service. I also need the server current timestamp. info/ just returns the timestamp of the build. Instead, I want the server current timestamp.

Comment: What do you mean by "current timestamp"? The system time of the server?

Comment: yeah. I mean the server time

Answer (score 0):

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-application-info-custom

You can simply add values that you need by providing an additional `InfoContributor`.

```
@Component
public class TimeInfoContributor implements InfoContributor {

    @Override
    public void contribute(Info.Builder builder) {
        // Calculate your desired timeValue here.
        builder.withDetail("time", timeValue);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. I would also need to the server time to actuator/health endpoint. All I can find in customizing the health endpoint is sending whether the service is up/down. Additionally I want to return the server time also. Is there any way to implement that

Comment: You can also add custom details to any health endpoint. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/health/Health.html